# #define с++ для чего служит

Tags: c++, define

например код:

```
1) #define PRIMERP 315
2) #define PRIMERF(V1 V2)(V1+2)*(V2+2)
int i = PRIMERP;
int j = PRIMERF(2,3);
```

хотелось бы уточнить 1 это своего рода константа а 2 это функция то же вроде константы и после компиляции cpp файла в exe файл, эти константы не будут включены в исполняемом файле,то есть если декомпилировать будет следующее

```
int i = 315;
int j = 20;
```

я правильно понимаю

Comment: [Препроцессор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80), [в си](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B8)

Comment: Директива препроцессора `#define` заменяет один кусок текста на другой. В этом примере в первом случае после замены действительно будет на `int i = 315;` однако `int j = (2+2)*(3+2);` во втором.

Comment: Вы бы хоть постарались корректно воспроизвести код. То, что вы написали - просто ошибочно (опечатки).

Comment: Если компилятор (после препроцессора) вычисляет константные выражения (обычно это так), то в принципе (с точностью до выбора декомпайлером имен), правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директива `#define` сама по себе осуществляет только текстовую подстановку, но не предвычисление выражений с константами. То есть, если исправить объявление PRIMERF на корректное (у вас пропущена запятая):

```
#define PRIMERF(V1,V2) (V1+2)*(V2+2)
```

, то на этапе обработки препроцессором `PRIMERF(2,3)` превратится в `(2+2)*(3+2)`.

Предвычисление константного выражения может быть выполнено на этапе компиляции, но это не гарантируется. Скажем, Visual C++ выполняет его, в том числе и при отключенной оптимизации:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRIMERP 315
#define PRIMERF(V1,V2)(V1+2)*(V2+2)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int i = PRIMERP;
    int j = PRIMERF(2,3);
    printf("%d %d",i,j);
    ;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

/* Disassembly:

_main:
 push        ebp  
 mov         ebp,esp  
 sub         esp,8  
 push        esi  
 mov         dword ptr [j],0CCCCCCCCh  
 mov         dword ptr [i],0CCCCCCCCh  
 mov         dword ptr [i],13Bh           // int i = PRIMERP;
 mov         dword ptr [j],14h            // int j = PRIMERF(2,3);
 mov         esi,esp  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [j]  
 push        eax  
 mov         ecx,dword ptr [i]  
 push        ecx  
 push        0F05858h  
 call        dword ptr ds:[0F092C0h]  // printf("%d %d",i,j);
 add         esp,0Ch  
 cmp         esi,esp  
 call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0F01220h)  
 mov         esi,esp  
 call        dword ptr ds:[0F092C8h]  // getchar();
 cmp         esi,esp  
 call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0F01220h)  
 xor         eax,eax  
 pop         esi  
 add         esp,8  
 cmp         ebp,esp  
 call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0F01220h)  
 mov         esp,ebp  
 pop         ebp  
 ret  
*/
```

14h - это предвычисленное значение выражения (20 в шестнадцатеричном виде)